# RxJs - what's the difference among observer.isStopped, observer.observer.isStopped and observed.m.isDisposed

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'd like to find a way to detect whether a observer has finished using a customized observable, which  I created with Rx.Observable.create, such that the customized observable can end it and do some clean up properly.

So I created some test code as below to figure out what kind of fields are available on the observer object for this purpose.

```
var Rx = require("rx")

var source = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {

  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    observer.onNext(i);
    console.dir(observer);
    i+=1
  }, 1000)

});

var subscription = source.take(2).subscribe(
  function (x) { console.log('onNext: %s', x); }
);
```

The output is as following

```
onNext: 0
{ isStopped: false,
  observer: 
   { isStopped: false,
     _onNext: [Function],
     _onError: [Function],
     _onCompleted: [Function] },
  m: { isDisposed: false, current: { dispose: [Function] } } }
onNext: 1
onCompleted
{ isStopped: true,
  observer: 
   { isStopped: false,
     _onNext: [Function],
     _onError: [Function],
     _onCompleted: [Function] },
  m: { isDisposed: true, current: null } }
```

It seems there are 3 fields on the observer object which seem to have something to do withmy goal, namely, observer.isStopped, observer.observer.isStopped and observer.m.isDiposed.

I was wondering what they all are about and which one I should choose.

==============================================================================
Motivations for my question

Based on Andre's suggestion, I add the scenario which motivated my question.

In my application, I was trying to do some UI animations based on the window.requestAnimationFrame(callback) mechanism.  requestAnimationFrame will call the provided callback in a time determined by the browser render engine. The callback is supposed to do some animation step and recursively call requestAnimationFrame again until the end of animation.

I want to abstract this mechanism to an observable as below.

```
function animationFrameRenderingEventsObservable(){
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(subscriber){
        var fn = function(frameTimestmpInMs){
            subscriber.onNext(frameTimestmpInMs);
            window.requestAnimationFrame(fn)
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrameb(fn);
    });
}
```

Then I can use it in various places where animation are needed. For one example, I need to draw some animation UNTIL the user touch the screen, I go

```
 animationFrameRenderingEventsObservable()
   .takeUntil(touchStartEventObservable)
   .subscribe( animationFunc )
```

However, I need a way to stop the infinite recursion in animationFrameRenderingEventsObservable after the takeUntil(touchStartEventObservable) has ended the subscription.

Therefore, I modified animationFrameRenderingEventsObservable to

```
function animationFrameRenderingEventsObservable(){
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(subscriber){
        var fn = function(frameTimestmpInMs){
            if (!subscriber.isStopped){
                subscriber.onNext(frameTimestmpInMs);
                window.requestAnimationFrame(fn)
            }else{
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrameb(fn);
    });
}
```

According to my test, the code works as expected. But, if, as Andre mentioned, use subscriber.isStopped or alike is not a correct way to so, then what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function you supply to `create`, you can return a cleanup function to call when the observer unsubscribes from your observable.  You should supply a function which stops your animation frame requests.  Here's a working observable that does what you want that I wrote a few years ago:

```
Rx.Observable.animationFrames = function () {
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an observable that triggers on every animation frame (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame ).
    /// The value that comes through the observable is the time(ms) since the previous frame (or the time since the subscribe call for the first frame)
    /// </summary>
    var request = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame,
        cancel = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame || window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msCancelAnimationFrame || window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame;

    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        var requestId,
            startTime = window.mozAnimationStartTime || Date.now(),
            callback = function (currentTime) {
                // If we have not been disposed, then request the next frame
                if (requestId !== undefined) {
                    requestId = request(callback);
                }

                observer.onNext(Math.max(0, currentTime - startTime));
                startTime = currentTime;
            };

        requestId = request(callback);

        return function () {
            if (requestId !== undefined) {
                var r = requestId;
                requestId = undefined;
                cancel(r);
            }
        };
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
Rx.Observable.animationFrames().take(5).subscribe(function (msSinceLastFrame) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using observer.isStopped or related, you doing something wrong. These are not API functions, they are implementation details.

> I'd like to find a way to detect whether a observer has finished using a customized observable, which I created with Rx.Observable.create, such that the customized observable can end it and do some clean up properly.

Observers do clean up when 'onCompleted' happens. In the Observable.create above, you should call `observer.onCompleted()` when you consider the custom observable to have ended, or never call `observer.onCompleted()` if the custom observable is meant to be infinite. Also, you should wrap the whole code inside Observable.create with try/catch and call `observer.onError(err)` in the catch.

If you are trying to make the Observable "clean up" when an observer "has finished using the observable", then you are doing it wrong. Essentially, if the custom observable needs to react to the observer, then it means the observer should also be an observable. Likely, Observable.create is not the tool for this.

Better tell what you are trying to accomplish instead of how to do something specific.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the animations you want to do: in the context of RxJS, requestAnimationFrame is a Scheduler, not an Observable. [Use it from the RxJS-DOM library](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/schedulers/requestanimationframescheduler.md).

Comment: Andre, I updated my question to include the scenario which can explain my motivation.

Comment: _Essentially, if the custom observable needs to react to the observer, then it means the observer should also be an observable_ *NOT TRUE* Rx establishes a communication channel from the observer back to the observable for 2 specific events: observable is notified when the observer *subscribes*, and observer is notified when the observer *unsubscribes*.  It is this mechanism that allows for cold and hot observables, and more fundamentally, lazy observables that do not consume resources if no one is watching.

Comment: While Andre's solution of using requestAnimationFrame scheduler is a perfect answer for my original scenario, Brandon's solution is more relevant to what I asked for in this question. So I choose his one.

Comment: Yes, I liked his solution too.

Comment: The `requestAnimationFrame` scheduler cannot be used to sample certain events and drop others, can it? (Like mouse events that otherwise hurt performance.) I imagine we'd still need an observable for that, combined with `.sample`.